# What are the JavaScript libraries required to contribute to Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I would like to embed Node-RED app in my Angular application, which uses loopback API. I could embed Node-RED with loopback App so it also runs on the same port. I would like to learn the core libraries required to customise Node-RED. So that I too can contribute.

Please suggest me the libraries for custom UI, writing user activity log, create dashboard/Analytics view.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why anonymous people are down-voting Node-RED questions? Perhaps people would be a bit more transparent about that so that others can improve the questions.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have somewhat confused what Node-RED is and what Angular is.

Node-RED is a **server** application whereas Angular is a **browser** library.

So you cannot embed Node-RED into an Angular app.

You use Node-RED to serve up an Angular App and provide either (or both) an API service or a websocket interface to your front-end Angular app.

Indeed, Node-RED already provides an Angular v1 single-page app in the form of "Dashboard".